# Run SQL job from Ruby on Rails App

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to run a SQL job from Ruby on Rails application?

Comment: SQL Server, probably, right? Will RoR run on windows as well? Same server, different server?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to the SQL Server's msdb database and call **sp_start_job** just like any other stored procedure.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'Myjob'
```

There is also a way with VBScript that I have not tried. Both solutions are documented here:
http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1730